# Missing expression and then group function not allowed error

Tags: sql, select, plsql, jdeveloper

I am wondering what i am doing wrong. I have 2 tables 
`ODETAILS` and `ORDERS`

`ODETAILS` has the following columns: ONO, PNO, QTY, COST
`ORDERS` has the following columns: ONO, CNO, ENO, RECEIVED, SHIPPED, ORDER_COST

```
UPDATE ORDERS
SET ORDER_COST= 1 *  SUM(
    SELECT COST
    FROM ODETAILS
    WHERE ORDERS.PNO=ODETAILS.PNO
    )
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HAH. figured it out. there is no PNO in ORDERS table.

```
UPDATE ORDERS
SET ORDER_COST= 
    (SELECT sum(COST)
    FROM ODETAILS
    WHERE ORDERS.ONO=ODETAILS.ONO);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. (sum was in wrong place)

```
UPDATE ORDERS
SET ORDER_COST= 1 *  (
    SELECT SUM(COST)
    FROM ODETAILS
    WHERE ORDERS.PNO=ODETAILS.PNO
    )
;
```